# Getting a specific date from today()

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I currently use the following code to give me the date of today as yyyymm.

```
Today = FORMAT(TODAY(), "yyyymm")
```

The problem is that I need to get the same format `yyyymm` for 6 months from now

So if today is 201903, I need 201909.

I have been able to return the month, 6 months from now with:

`6MonthsFromNow = MONTH(TODAY()) + 6`

But that doesn't really help me as I need the year and month as `yyyymm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
6MonthsFromNow = FORMAT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY());(MONTH(TODAY()) + 6);DAY(TODAY())); "yyyymm")
```

**Edit** - as pointed out by some comment, the standard separator is "," not ";" anyway they both work.

Comment: This won't work in the second half of the year due to the assumption that the year is the same. Put a Dateadd() around Today () and then format as normal.

Comment: I don't think so. Docs says that year is augmented in the right way, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/date-function-dax

Comment: Oh, interesting. I was not aware it was smart like that. Today I learned.

Answer (score 1):

```
6 mos = FORMAT(EDATE(Today(), 6),"yyyymm")
```

Add 6 months to today using Edate, then format as normal.

Comment: Did you try this? DATEADD does **non** accept today() as argument, it wants a column name as argument.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry, forgot about that. You can use edate instead.